# MongoItemReader should read only distinct values of the keys

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-mongo

I'm using Spring Batch to calculate score based on several documents with a specific key having same value. Now my processor calculates the score for each unique value of the key by aggregating by that key, so the reader calculated the score every time it encounters another document with same value.

I tried to [`setQuery`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html#setQuery-java.lang.String-) of [`MongoItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html) to read only distinct data, but it only supports [`BasicQuery`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/BasicQuery.html) not [`Aggregation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html).
I then tried to extend the `MongoItemReader` & override its `doPageRead` method, but `MongoItemReader` doesn't provide any getters. So then I tweaked `MongoItemReader` class's [`doPageRead`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html#doPageRead--) method to use `Aggregation` & [`MongoTemplate.aggregate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#aggregate-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) but I lose the [`Pageable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) functionality of [`AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader.html) provided with `BasicQuery`.